# Enumerated headings using apa6?

Tags: sectioning, apa6

The `apa6` document class doesn't use enumerated headings, but I want my headings to look like:

1. Something

1.1 Something

1.2 Something

2. Something

2.1 Something

etc...

How do I enable this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. As it stands, your posting is quite terse. Do you want sectioning headers with just numbers and no titles. Incidentally, `apa6` can be both a document class and a LaTeX package. Please confirm which possibility applies.

Comment: Aah, good point. I'll update my post. I'm using it in my documentclass -- is this not a package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class does

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
```

so sectional units below `\part` are not numbered. If you want to number them, you need to increase the counter to the desired level:

```
\documentclass{apa6}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because of how `apa6` works, Gonzalo Medina's answer is not quite enough on its own (at least when running in `man` mode -- I haven't checked the other output formats). You will end up with "1 Abstract", "2 {paper title}", "3 Introduction", and any subsections in appendices will have confusing numbers attached. For numbering just the sections within the main body of the article, and skipping numbering subsections within appendices:

- Put `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` immediately after your call to `\maketitle`
- Put `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` immediately before your `\bibliography`.